# Регулярное выражение ссылки с протоколом HTTPS

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Делаю парсинг ссылки при помощи следующего кода:

```
m = re.search('http\://([^/]*)/?.*', url)
host = m.group(1)
```

Но если вставить ссылку с https, то возникнет ошибка:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Можно ли как-то переписать код таким образом, чтобы функция `.search` могла принимать и http и https одновременно?

Comment: можно так: `re.search('http[s]?\://([^/]*)/?.*', url)`, но лучше все таки делать это специальными модулями...

Comment: Советую проверять, было ли совпадение: `m = re.search(...)`, `if m:`, `host=m.group(1)`, иначе таких ошибок не избежать. А необязательность одного символа можно определить с помощью квантификатора `?`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Конечно возможно

```
m = re.search('https?://([^/]*)/?.*', url)
host = m.group(1)
```

Answer (score 6):

Можно изменить регулярное выражение на такое:

```
'https?\://([^/]*)/?.*'
```

но так как Вы не знаете даже основ регулярных выражений, то не рекомендую Вам их использовать в реальных задачах.
В Python есть модуль `urllib.parse` и функция `urlparse` в нём:

```
>>> import urllib.parse as urlparse
>>> urlparse.urlparse( 'https://google.com/q=' ).netloc
'google.com'
```